# Not able to change label on CCBFile after loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

To preface this, I was doing the tutorials from SpriteBuilder, and one of them was a simple Flappy Bird remake. The restart button was a bit plain so I decided to add my own touch to it, a layer that shows the players score that shows when the bird crashes.

I am trying to display a CCBFile, `gameOverLayer`, onto my `MainScene`. The `gameOverLayer` is just a layer that contains the label "Game Over" and has your score and high score on it. I am calling `[self gameOver]` when the player fails the level, and that method has the code for displaying the CCBFile onto the screen. This works just fine, but when I try to update the label by calling `_scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _points];` ,also in `-(void)gameOver`, it doesn't display anything. I thought it may be an issue with my point system, so I replaced it with `_scoreLabel.string = @"test"`. That did not work either.

What seems weird to me is that when I call `_scoreLabel.string = @"test"` in my `viewDidLoad` method it works just fine, but when I do the same in `-(void)gameOver` it does not update the label.

Here is what I am doing...

[Displaying the CCBFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HJlG.jpg)

[Displaying the CCBFile 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBqhZ.jpg)

[GameOver.ccb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/295mf.jpg)

I create the CCBFile as so

MainScene.h:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) CCNode *gameOverLayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) CCLabelTTF *finalScoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) CCLabelTTF *bestScoreLabel;
```

and I hide the `gameOverLayer` in viewDidLoad as so

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    _gameOverLayer.visible = NO;
}
```

Then in `-(void)gameOver`

```
_finalScoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _points];
_bestScoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _best];
```

I've tried a few simple things, but it seems that it is more complicated than just updating the label in `gameOver`. It seems as if once the layer loads, you can't change the labels on it, which seems a bit odd to me. Any ideas? Greatly appreciate any replies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```
[_finalScoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _points]];
[_bestScoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _best]];
```

You are using string like a proper, but looking at the label headers I don't see any defined string property. Just manually typed getter and setter methods like this.